# Lost module while installing opencv 2.4.9 for python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, opencv, installation

I try to install opencv from source. I use Visual studio 2010, python 2.7.8 and make steps like [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html).

The problem is that when importing cv2 I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

There are following cv-files in the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`:

```
cv2.pyd
cv.py
cv.pyc
```

I also have Python 3.4.1 but CMake doesn't see that, so I think it is not the reason.

But CMake has just two lines in the PYTHON group:

```
PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR         C:/Python27/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH             C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my install of OpenCV for Windows, built with MinGW for C++ includes.

[image]

It's not actually an install - the folder can be zipped and put on any computer, provided you specify to CMake the paths.